# Pass HTML to Control ToolTip from C#

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, .net

I have a control (ImageButton) which is getting it's ToolTip property set in the code behind. The control resides in a UserControl, which is hooked up to a Repeater Control. I am passing some data to the ImageButton tooltip in HTML format:

```
        public static string BuildPaymentToolTip(List<PaymentView> payments)
    {
        string toolTip = string.Empty;

        string header = "<table><tr><td>Payment Id</td><td>Payment Amount</td><td>Comment</td><td>Status</td><td>Pull Date</td><td>Created Date</td></tr>";

        foreach (var p in payments)
        {
            toolTip = toolTip +
                "<tr><td>" + p.Id +
                "</td><td>" + string.Format("{0:N2}", p.PaymentAmount) +
                "</td><td>" + Helper.TruncateString(p.Comment, 50, "...") +
                "</td><td>" + ((PaymentTrackingStatusEnum)p.PaymentTrackingStatusId).ToString() +
                "</td><td>" + (p.PaymentPullDate.HasValue ? p.PaymentPullDate.Value.ToShortDateString() : String.Empty) +
                "</td><td>" + p.CreateDate.ToShortDateString() +
                "</td></tr>";
        }

        return header + toolTip + "</table>";
    }
```

It's being sent properly, but is being rendered as plain text rather than HTML...

The catch is that I have another page, basically using the same type of helper class, but the tooltip displays it in HTML format correctly. The only difference is that this is a regular aspx page, whereas the one that is not working is an ascx. Is there a reason that this would make a difference?

Thank you!!

EDIT:

Here is the one that is working. This one is outputting user information to a different ImageButton element.

```
    public string BuildToolTipUserInformation(int createdById, DateTime createDate, int lastUpdatedById, DateTime lastUpdatedDate)
    {
        string toolTip = string.Empty;

        var helper = new UserInfoHelper();
        string userName = helper.GetCreatedByFullUserName(createdById);
        string lastUpdatedBy = helper.GetUpdatedByFullUserName(lastUpdatedById);

        toolTip = "<table><tr><td>User Information:</td></tr><tr><td>Created By: </td><td>" + userName +
            "</td></tr><tr><td>Created Date:</td><td>" + createDate +
            "</td></tr><tr><td> Last Updated By:</td><td>" + lastUpdatedBy +
            "</td><tr><td>Last Updated Date:</td><td>" + lastUpdatedDate +
            "</tr></td></tr></table>";

        return toolTip;
    }
```

Comment: You realize you are closing the `</table>` on every iteration of the loop - probably not what you intended (as it isn't valid HTML).

Comment: Good call! Although, none of the HTML is being rendered, so at the moment it didn't matter :)

Comment: Is it possible that it's not rendering as HTML (and instead as plaintext), because it is invalid? You say this is working on another `ascx` page - are you using the **exact** same `BuildPaymentToolTip` method, or something *similar* (that possibly does not have this HTML error?)

Comment: I fixed the error, it didn't change anything. It's rendering it as plain text and displaying all of the HTML markup.

Comment: Do you want to update the original source now that you've changed it?

Set a breakpoint on `return header + toolTip;` and verify that the string being generated is what you expect in terms of HTML.

Comment: This is the output...it is correct

<table>
 <tr>
  <td>Payment Id</td>
  <td>Payment Amount</td>
  <td>Comment</td>
  <td>Status</td>
  <td>Pull Date</td>
  <td>Created Date</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>16258</td>
  <td>200.00</td>
  <td>test</td>
  <td>AppMg</td>
  <td></td>
  <td>12/2/2014</td>
 </tr>
</table>